# Is it possible to format numbers in Azure Powerapps chart?

Tags: azure, powerapps

I am working on Powerapp application. Want to show the Cost (In $) for the last 12 months in a Powerapp bar chart. But I don't see any option to format the numbers to add $ symbol at the end.

I feel this is a very basic requirement in charts and can't find a way to do it in powerapps.

Is there any workaround for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer **NO,It is not possible !**

You are looking to format the `series` value in the Chart Features of the PowerApps.

Column Chart Properties --> Advanced

[image]

As far As I have researched only the, `Labels` ( The X - axis) feature can be will be formatted where as the `series` will always a numerical value.  (Despite adding the Currency Format)

You can add the currency format using the below code :

```
AddColumns(<TableName>,"currency",Text(<numbervalue>,"[$-en-US]$###,###.00") )
```

However, this will not be helpful in formatting the `Series` Value

If you use the updated column as label :

[image]

*Understand* , this may not suit the requirement - but sharing just in case you get alternate ideas.

**Other workaround :**

If you are persisting the data outside - you use Power BI Embed to Visually represent the data. If real time visualization of data is not a requirement - this would be your Solution.

Unfortunately, you cannot use PowerBI Embed to Visualize the In-Memory Powerapp Collection (Live data).Also,the data might not be near real time ( the sync will have to take place in order to reflect the new data).

If visualizing a real time data is mandatory for you, you could use [streaming dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-real-time-streaming) to get real time data & display in the POwer BI embed Visuals - but then it has its downsides.

**Note :**
There is an  idea submitted for the same below :

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Ideas/Line-Chart-Format-Y-axis-as-currency/idi-p/458154